# Deploying to Heroku a Rails 4 + AngularJS website using Bower

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, heroku, bower

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 4 + AngularJS app to Heroku.

The problem is Heroku does not see the bower_components in my vendor/assets file even though I've added the path to my application.rb file

```
  config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('vendor', 'assets', 'bower_components')
```

Heroku push origin master:

```
   -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
   Running: rake assets:precompile
   ...
   rake aborted!
   Sprockets::FileNotFound: couldn't find file 'angular'
   (in /tmp/build_e660cd4b8a3168401ec4da7e261784fe/app/assets/javascripts/application.js:18)
```

I'm using the Bowerfile but bowerrails does not create a bower.json file.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the problem is due to the fact that bower is not being installed nor installing the components. If these two don't happen, it won't be able to find your assets.

Adding a custom buildpack to heroku and configuring the app package helped me to get through it. Take a look at this coderwall post that takes it step by step.

https://coderwall.com/p/6bmygq/heroku-rails-bower

Answer (score -3):

Try precompiling and committing to git before pushing.

```
rake assets:precompile

git commit -am 'Precompiled Angular.'

git push heroku master
```

Usually works for me.

Comment: I really hate having to include all that precompiled garb in my git repo tho... that just feels wrong...

Comment: This adds a step more to my development cycle